# Opencv cvSetImageROI coordinate issue

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing, uiimage, crop

in my app i used opencv to cropped an image with specific coordinate, but the problem it was when i move the coord of the left side it was the up side make change so i didn't understand.

```
//assignment of calculates ration between view resolution and resolution of the photograph
double scaleX = (outPutImage.frame.size.width/newCoordRect.imgWidth);
double scaleY = (outPutImage.frame.size.height/newCoordRect.imgHeight);

//assignment of the values after calculates coordinates
int x = newCoordRect.leftUp.x/(scaleX);
int y = newCoordRect.leftUp.y/(scaleY);

int heigth = ((newCoordRect.rightDown.y-newCoordRect.rightUp.y)/scaleY);
int width = ((newCoordRect.rightDown.x-newCoordRect.leftUp.x)/scaleX);

/* load image */
IplImage *img1 = [[ShareFunction sFunction]CreateIplImageFromUIImage:outPutImage.image];

/* sets the Region of Interest
 Note that the rectangle area has to be __INSIDE__ the image */
cvSetImageROI(img1, cvRect(x, y, width, heigth));

/* create destination image
 Note that cvGetSize will return the width and the height of ROI */
IplImage *img2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img1),
                               img1->depth,
                               3);

/* copy subimage */
cvCopy(img1, img2, NULL);

/* always reset the Region of Interest */
cvResetImageROI(img1);

retCropImg = [[ShareFunction sFunction]UIImageFromIplImage:img2];
```

any idea?

Comment: I think the C tag is much more appropriate than crop or cropping, and also has a lot more followers. Consider re-tagging it.

Comment: ok thx but i already found solution i had needed to rotate my uiimage and after that work.

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be right.
Have a look at the orientation of the image